# How to download files from remote windows server

Tags: python, windows, paramiko

What would be the best way of downloading / uploading files / directory to / from remote windows server and local windows machine using python scripting language?

Modules I heard of are paramiko and fabric...

Apart from these any other good option/choice?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the protocol you are using, if the file is big, use UDP, if the file is small use TCP, if the file is small use SSH. You don's necessarily need paramiko or fabric to communicate with another computer, since they are for ssh connections. If you know the protocol, then it is easier to communicate.

Comment: I want it to be automated, that is why I need a Python script... Suppose if I know that the protocol is TCP, how can we achieve this as per you?

Comment: So basically you require a program that gets lines from a file and writes it one by one in ORDER to a file (i have had this problem). The lines you get from the remote server.